# What does "set" mean in llvm TableGen files?

Tags: llvm

I read the llvm backend for AVR. What does "set" mean in llvm TableGen? How do I write the pattern for the instruction "mov"? Like as follows?

```py
(set ACC:$rd,(mov GPR8:$src));
```

Another code from AVR backend as follows:

```py
def ADDRdRr : FRdRr<0b0000,
                      0b11,
                      (outs GPR8:$rd),
                      (ins GPR8:$src, GPR8:$rr),
                      "add\t$rd, $rr",
                      [(set i8:$rd, (add i8:$src, i8:$rr)),
                       (implicit SREG)]>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern matches an addition operation and `set` means that the result of addition should be placed in `$rd` operand. As you can see, this is exactly the operand marked as "output" - `(outs GPR8:$rd)`.

Regarding `mov` instruction, in my toy backend I didn't even needed to specify a pattern for it. My `mov` definition looks like

```
def MovRR : InstRR<7, (outs IntRegs:$reg2), (ins IntRegs:$reg1),
                "mov $reg1, $reg2", []>;
```

Instead of matching, I implemented `MyBackendInstrInfo::copyPhysReg()`:

```
void MyBackendInstrInfo::copyPhysReg(MachineBasicBlock &MBB, MachineBasicBlock::iterator MI,
                                    const DebugLoc &DL, unsigned DestReg, unsigned SrcReg,
                                    bool KillSrc) const
{
    if (MB::IntRegsRegClass.contains(DestReg, SrcReg))
        BuildMI(MBB, MI, DL, get(MB::MovRR), DestReg)
            .addReg(SrcReg, getKillRegState(KillSrc));
    else
        llvm_unreachable("Impossible reg-to-reg copy");
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! A great example and explanation!! I see. The patterns do nothing else, just match the DAG fragments.